# How do I make authenticated requests to AWS using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, amazon-web-services

Amazon's documentation has a handy full example of making authenticated requests from Python:

```
# AWS Version 4 signing example

# EC2 API (DescribeRegions)

# See: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html
# This version makes a GET request and passes the signature
# in the Authorization header.
import sys, os, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac 
import requests # pip install requests

# ************* REQUEST VALUES *************
method = 'GET'
service = 'ec2'
host = 'ec2.amazonaws.com'
region = 'us-east-1'
endpoint = 'https://ec2.amazonaws.com'
request_parameters = 'Action=DescribeRegions&Version=2013-10-15'

# Key derivation functions. See:
# http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-python
def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()

def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), dateStamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
    return kSigning

# Read AWS access key from env. variables or configuration file. Best practice is NOT
# to embed credentials in code.
access_key = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
secret_key = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
if access_key is None or secret_key is None:
    print 'No access key is available.'
    sys.exit()

# Create a date for headers and the credential string
t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
amzdate = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
datestamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d') # Date w/o time, used in credential scope


# ************* TASK 1: CREATE A CANONICAL REQUEST *************
# http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html

# Step 1 is to define the verb (GET, POST, etc.)--already done.

# Step 2: Create canonical URI--the part of the URI from domain to query 
# string (use '/' if no path)
canonical_uri = '/' 

# Step 3: Create the canonical query string. In this example (a GET request),
# request parameters are in the query string. Query string values must
# be URL-encoded (space=%20). The parameters must be sorted by name.
# For this example, the query string is pre-formatted in the request_parameters variable.
canonical_querystring = request_parameters

# Step 4: Create the canonical headers and signed headers. Header names
# and value must be trimmed and lowercase, and sorted in ASCII order.
# Note that there is a trailing \n.
canonical_headers = 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amzdate + '\n'

# Step 5: Create the list of signed headers. This lists the headers
# in the canonical_headers list, delimited with ";" and in alpha order.
# Note: The request can include any headers; canonical_headers and
# signed_headers lists those that you want to be included in the 
# hash of the request. "Host" and "x-amz-date" are always required.
signed_headers = 'host;x-amz-date'

# Step 6: Create payload hash (hash of the request body content). For GET
# requests, the payload is an empty string ("").
payload_hash = hashlib.sha256('').hexdigest()

# Step 7: Combine elements to create create canonical request
canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash


# ************* TASK 2: CREATE THE STRING TO SIGN*************
# Match the algorithm to the hashing algorithm you use, either SHA-1 or
# SHA-256 (recommended)
algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
credential_scope = datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request'
string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amzdate + '\n' +  credential_scope + '\n' +  hashlib.sha256(canonical_request).hexdigest()


# ************* TASK 3: CALCULATE THE SIGNATURE *************
# Create the signing key using the function defined above.
signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, datestamp, region, service)

# Sign the string_to_sign using the signing_key
signature = hmac.new(signing_key, (string_to_sign).encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()


# ************* TASK 4: ADD SIGNING INFORMATION TO THE REQUEST *************
# The signing information can be either in a query string value or in 
# a header named Authorization. This code shows how to use a header.
# Create authorization header and add to request headers
authorization_header = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + access_key + '/' + credential_scope + ', ' +  'SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature

# The request can include any headers, but MUST include "host", "x-amz-date", 
# and (for this scenario) "Authorization". "host" and "x-amz-date" must
# be included in the canonical_headers and signed_headers, as noted
# earlier. Order here is not significant.
# Python note: The 'host' header is added automatically by the Python 'requests' library.
headers = {'x-amz-date':amzdate, 'Authorization':authorization_header}


# ************* SEND THE REQUEST *************
request_url = endpoint + '?' + canonical_querystring

print '\nBEGIN REQUEST++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'
print 'Request URL = ' + request_url
r = requests.get(request_url, headers=headers)

print '\nRESPONSE++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'
print 'Response code: %d\n' % r.status_code
print r.text
```

It doesn't have one for Node.js, though. So I attempted to translate that whole thing into Node:

```
var request = require('request');
var Crypto = require("crypto-js");
var strftime = require('strftime');

function sign(key, msg) {
    return Crypto.HmacSHA256(key, msg, {asBytes: true});
}

function getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName) {
    var kDate = sign(dateStamp, 'AWS4' + key);
    var kRegion = sign(regionName, kDate);
    var kService = sign(serviceName, kRegion);
    var kSigning = sign('aws4_request', kService);

    return kSigning;
}

function sha256(str) {
    return Crypto.SHA256(str);
}

// ************* REQUEST VALUES *************
var method = 'GET';
var service = 'ec2';
var host = 'ec2.amazonaws.com';
var region = 'us-east-1';
var endpoint = 'https://ec2.amazonaws.com';
var request_parameters = 'Action=DescribeRegions&Version=2013-10-15';

var access_key = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID;
var secret_key = process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;

var date = new Date();
var amzdate = strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ', date);
var datestamp = strftime('%Y%m%d', date);

// ************* TASK 1: CREATE A CANONICAL REQUEST *************
var canonical_uri = '/';
var canonical_querystring = request_parameters;
var canonical_headers = 'host:' + host + '\n' + 'x-amz-date:' + amzdate + '\n';
var signed_headers = 'host;x-amz-date';

var payload_hash = sha256('');
var canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash;

// ************* TASK 2: CREATE THE STRING TO SIGN*************
var algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256';
var credential_scope = datestamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request';
var string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' +  amzdate + '\n' +  credential_scope + '\n' +  sha256(canonical_request);

// ************* TASK 3: CALCULATE THE SIGNATURE *************
var signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, datestamp, region, service);
var signature = sign(signing_key, string_to_sign);

// ************* TASK 4: ADD SIGNING INFORMATION TO THE REQUEST *************
var authorization_header = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + access_key + '/' + credential_scope + ', ' +  'SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature;
var headers = {'x-amz-date':amzdate, 'Authorization':authorization_header, host: host};
var request_url = endpoint + '?' + canonical_querystring;

var options = {
    url: request_url,
    headers: headers
};

request(options, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res.statusCode, res.body);
});
```

When I set the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` in my shell to appropriate values from my AWS account and run the Python script, I get back status 200 with a bunch of data. But when I run my Node.js script, I get status code 401 and a body that says `AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials`. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: did you take a look at this: https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/ ? Should provide some more info about sending authenticated requests to AWS. 

Official library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk

People have made some smaller libraries for specific services as well. e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3

Comment: Yeah I checked out the official SDK but it just gives you black-box functions you can call to access its supported services and doesn't help you make your own authenticated requests. It doesn't support Amazon Elasticsearch Service, the one I need to hit, so I'm on my own.

Comment: Any success in translating it to node js?

Comment: I am stuck trying to do the same thing with S3 right now

Comment: Thank you for the code. I am getting 403 forbidden errors. So close but unable to finish the swing.

Comment: Another issue with just using the SDK is of course if try to run this in something time sensitive, like a lambda, the warmup could be a matter of added seconds. I have so far found only this little lib, but not yet tested it:
https://github.com/mhart/aws4

Comment: @LiorKupers v3 of the SDK says "Due to the limitations around reducing the size of the SDK when only using a handful of services or operations, many customers requested having separate packages for each service client. We have also split up the core parts of the SDK so that service clients only pull in what they need. For example, a service sends responses in JSON will no longer need to also have an XML parser as a dependency."

Comment: Very true @jsindos, but i'm talking about a lambda here where every ms is critical. In such cases, it is best to avoid installing as much as possible over npm...

Answer (score 7):

Well.. I guess I am 4 years late, but I am replying in case it helps someone else:

There is a sample in AWS documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-request-signing.html#es-request-signing-node

If you have the credentials in advance and you need to set them you can do something like this:

var credentials = new AWS.Credentials({ accessKeyId: 'KIA3...', secretAccessKey: '9wqwAvpht...', sessionToken: null });

For security reasons you don't want to hardcode your accessKey and secret key in your code so you will need to encrypt them, or use ssm or kms :-)

Comment: really helpful...